How to scrape data from arbitrary number of row listings using python selenium?
So I'm trying to create a bot that identifies nft loan listings on blur that meet certain criteria such as the loans total value being 80% or less than its floor price or APY being greater than 100%. I've figured out the basics of loading up chrome using selenium and navigating to the correct section of the website to view a collections loans. But I'm struggling to actually extract the data from the table of loans. What id like to be able to do is extract the table of loan listings into an array of arrays or array of dictionaries, with each array/dictionary containing data representing each name, status, borrow amount, LTV, and APY.
What I have working thus far:
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

path = "/Users/#########/Desktop/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver"

# Create an instance of ChromeOptions
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("disable-infobars");

# Specify the path to the ChromeDriver
service = Service(path)

# Initialize the WebDriver with the service and options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Open Blur beanz collection and navigating to active loans page
driver.maximize_window
driver.get("https://blur.io/eth/collection/beanzofficial/loans")
time.sleep(3)
loan_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/button[2]")
loan_button.click()


I'm honestly new to selenium, so I've just been toying around with my intuition and chatgpt trying to solve this. The best guess I've had so far was the following bit of code that tried to extract the APY of all the loans. This did not work, as im sure there was some faulty intuition.
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'Text-sc-m23s7f-0 hAGCAO')


# Initialize an empty list to store the percentage values
percentages = []

# Iterate through each element and extract its text (which contains the percentage)
for element in elements:
    percentage = element.text
    percentages.append(percentage)

# Print the extracted percentage values
print(percentages)

time.sleep(10)
# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()

I also feel like this is a bit complex, having to extract each column in the table rather than each row at a time. Not sure if there is a simpler way to do this, if there was that would be great. If not ok too!

looks like blur will be coming out with an API soon-- make sure you submit the form to register for access as using an API is always MUCH faster/easier than using Selenium.  Edit: I found this form by clicking the "API" link at the bottom of the blur.io homepage

@ryyyn Oh thank you, I didnt see that. Although I'm really just attempting this project to get comfortable with selenium and to eventually build a little app to put on my resume. So if you have any advice for how to make this work with selenium it would be greatly appreciated! thanks again, cheers.

I would recommend searching "how to locate elements with Selenium" and doing some reading. But maybe this get you started...
Your XPATH to select the "ALL LOANS" button is /html/body/div/div/main/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/nav/button[2]--it's clear you got this by clicking "Copy XPATH" in developer console. This is generally not a good approach, because if anything about the page structure changes your code will break (imagine a developer decides to add or remove a div anywhere in that hierarchy). Instead, try to find a unique way to select the element that is unlikely to change. Selecting by ID (eg: driver.find_element(By.ID, "main-menu")) is preferred if possible. On this page, the "ALL LOANS" button doesn't have an ID nor a unique class name--in that case, I prefer using text to locate the element. My recommended XPATH would be: //button[.='All Loans']. This XPATH means, select all <button> elements anywhere on the page whose string content is equal to "All Loans". (Note that this text matching IS case sensitive--even though the text "ALL LOANS" displays uppercase on the page, if you examine the HTML code you can see the capitalization of the actual text).
To test an XPATH in Chrome, open the HTML viewer (Elements tab of developer console) and hit CTRL+F to open the Find searchbar, then enter your XPATH (without enclosing quotes). You will see how many elements are located using the XPATH.
For selecting the loans, you can use this XPATH: //div[@id= 'COLLECTION_MAIN']//div[@role='rowgroup']//div[@role='row']. First it locates the <div> with an id of 'COLLECTION_MAIN'--this is the center area of the screen. Then it locates the "rowgroup" div descendant element which contains the Loans, and finally all the rows themselves. You can try playing around with this XPATH--if you remove either of the first components of the selector it will not work, because it will locate additional divs with the 'row' role.
You can then iterate over these rows to get any details you want.
Putting it together:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

...

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
# disable the message "Chrome being controlled by automated test software"
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

# Open Blur beanz collection and navigating to active loans page
driver.maximize_window()  # fixed typo
driver.get("https://blur.io/eth/collection/beanzofficial/loans")
# wait until element is clickable then click it
loans_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[.='All Loans']")))
loans_button.click()

percentages = []

# wait for table to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id= 'COLLECTION_MAIN']//div[@role='rowgroup']//div[@role='row']")))

for loan_row in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id= 'COLLECTION_MAIN']//div[@role='rowgroup']//div[@role='row']"):
   apy = loan_row.find_element(By.XPATH, "div[5]").text # select the 5th column
   percentages.append(apy) # could use float(apy[:-1]) to convert to number

Edit: Andrej's answer is far superior in terms of ease and speed--using Selenium for data scraping should really be a last resort

This isn't filling up the percentages array for me. Did this work for you?

hmm, yes I tested it and it works for me... sorry in advance for this question but did you include the line to print percentages? (it's not in my code) -- Otherwise, do some manual debugging. Open a REPL and paste in the code line-by-line and see what values you get. This is super useful because you can try different selectors/different functions much quicker than re-running your script every time. (And this applies to any Python project, especially when working with something unfamiliar like web source code where you'll surely need to try different approaches)

yes i did include that haha. I probably made some other simple mistake somewhere, ill take a look and give your suggestion a try. Thank you so much for your responses, it has been quite the help!

I added the lines containing the path to the chrome driver and service = Service(path) to the "..." in your code and a print at the end, but its just printing a empty array! not sure what I could be missing here ;{

If it's not adding elements to the array, and it's not raising an Exception, it means that driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='COLLECTION_MAIN']//div[@role='rowgroup']//div[@role='row']") is returning an empty array... did you try running it line-by-line like I suggested? If that works for you but running as a script doesn't, maybe the site loads slower for you and so it needs a little delay after clicking the "ALL LOANS" button; you could try adding time.sleep(1)

Yes that was exactly it, thank you!

To get the table data I'd parse the <script> element where the data is stored in Json format:
import json

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://blur.io/"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.select_one("#__NEXT_DATA__").text)

table = data["props"]["pageProps"]["sections"]["tableCollections"]

for tab, data in zip(table["tabs"], table["data"]):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    del df["iconUrl"]

    values = df.pop("values").apply(pd.Series)
    values.columns = table["headings"][1:]

    df = pd.concat([df, values], axis=1)

    print(tab)
    print(df)
    print()

Prints:
Trending
                                                collectionUrl                                         title Floor Price 1D Change 7D Change 1D Volume 7D Volume  Owners  Supply
0                        https://blur.io/collection/lilpudgys                                     LilPudgys        0.67    -12.89    -22.77    149.34    855.78    8269   21663
1                       https://blur.io/collection/degods-eth                                        DeGods        0.77     -8.62    -32.22     49.83    640.14    2006    5679
2                           https://blur.io/collection/clonex                                        CloneX        0.40     -0.12     -4.52     42.39    219.07    9488   19600
3                    https://blur.io/collection/mypethooligan                               My Pet Hooligan        0.34     -4.39    -12.42      9.83     68.65    3528    8888
4              https://blur.io/collection/cryptochasers-robot                           CryptoChasers Robot        0.88      0.00      0.00      0.88      0.88     472     499
5                  https://blur.io/collection/proof-moonbirds                                     Moonbirds        0.38    -10.93    -19.20     17.23     97.76    5797   10000
6            https://blur.io/collection/bored-ape-kennel-club                            BoredApeKennelClub        0.29    -12.28    -20.81     33.17    162.73    5076    9602
7            https://blur.io/collection/influenceth-asteroids                           Influence Asteroids        0.02     55.83    -18.33      1.93      2.77    1936    9666
8    https://blur.io/collection/lacma-cactoid-labs-rotf-vol-1  LACMA Remembrance of Things Future Volume #1        0.30    -24.05    -24.53      0.20      1.15     118     500
9                    https://blur.io/collection/beanzofficial                                         Beanz        0.17    -19.08    -20.61     30.37    153.57    7677   19950
10  https://blur.io/collection/murakami-flowers-2022-official                              Murakami.Flowers        0.15     -0.07      5.57      1.29     11.11    5365   10153
11                   https://blur.io/collection/habbo-avatars                                 Habbo Avatars        0.12     -0.69     -4.17      1.49      8.76    4410   11599
12                      https://blur.io/collection/deadfellaz                                    DeadFellaz        0.07     -0.14     -4.27      0.56      1.98    6413   10000
13                    https://blur.io/collection/trainersgen1              Pixelmon Trainers - Generation 1        0.08    -13.26    -17.59      0.25     11.89    1254    7000
14                https://blur.io/collection/str8fire-og-pass                              STR8FIRE OG PASS        0.05    -14.11     39.15      0.17      3.48     548    1200

Top
                                       collectionUrl                    title Floor Price 1D Change 7D Change 1D Volume 7D Volume  Owners  Supply
0           https://blur.io/collection/pudgypenguins            PudgyPenguins        7.29    -22.60    -28.50    894.49   2565.28    5182    8888
1       https://blur.io/collection/boredapeyachtclub        BoredApeYachtClub        8.89    -12.17    -24.25    680.12   3546.91    5460    9998
2                  https://blur.io/collection/milady                   Milady        4.73     -0.46     15.29    279.38   3113.31    5135    9978
3   https://blur.io/collection/mutant-ape-yacht-club       MutantApeYachtClub        1.47    -13.48    -20.11    219.61   2203.20   11658   19495
4          https://blur.io/collection/remilio-babies  Redacted Remilio Babies        1.28     -9.81      4.56    209.64   1303.70    4610    9998
5               https://blur.io/collection/lilpudgys                LilPudgys        0.67    -12.89    -22.77    149.34    855.78    8269   21663
6                   https://blur.io/collection/azuki                    Azuki        3.20    -10.64    -15.13    128.56   1994.88    4255   10000
7              https://blur.io/collection/degods-eth                   DeGods        0.77     -8.62    -32.22     49.09    640.54    2005    5679
8           https://blur.io/collection/kanpai-pandas            Kanpai Pandas        0.79    -15.17    -16.16     48.26    330.87    3191    7976
9                  https://blur.io/collection/clonex                   CloneX        0.40     -0.12     -4.52     42.39    219.07    9488   19600
10           https://blur.io/collection/pixelmongen1                 Pixelmon        0.44    -10.41     -9.65     37.48    191.28    2599   12566
11  https://blur.io/collection/bored-ape-kennel-club       BoredApeKennelClub        0.29    -12.28    -20.81     33.17    162.73    5076    9602
12                https://blur.io/collection/persona                  Persona        0.22    -11.29    -13.96     30.89    200.20    3222    8875
13            https://blur.io/collection/sappy-seals              Sappy Seals        0.42    -13.36    -18.76     30.79    135.66    1618    9997
14          https://blur.io/collection/beanzofficial                    Beanz        0.17    -19.08    -20.61     30.37    153.57    7677   19950


How would I then get the Loan Data from this? This is very helpful thank you!

@number2patrician And where is loan data located?

https://blur.io/eth/collection/azuki/loans for example is the loan page for the azuki collection. I just want a way to get all the information on the active loans for this collection and similar collections of NFTs! thanks again!
